# How to customize container width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to customize the width of the class container in bootstrap.
The width I would like to obtain is **670px**.
I customized the bootstrap.css file (http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) in order to obtain my own version.
The code below shows how container has been customized.
From 749px the width does not change as expected.
Do you know how to fix it?

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.container {
width: 670px;
background: green;
}
 }

@media (min-width: 992px) {
.container {
 width: 670px;
}
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.container {
 width: 670px;
}
 }
```

Comment: This is not the right class to edit the with. This is media query only affects when your screen size is small.
Go find .container and change it over there

Answer (score -1):

Add '!important' after the value, like this code:
     @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
    width: 670px!important;
    background: green;
    }
     }

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
.container {
 width: 670px!important;
}
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.container {
 width: 670px!important;
}
 }
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".